# How to set Relation property in ActiveRecord-Model?

Tags: php, yii

I've tried To set a related property of an activeRecord Model with an instance of the related class from the **belongsTo** relationship, but when I call the `save()` method I get an Error because an invalid foreign Key constraint.

Should I set the id to the related record manually?

Comment: please post a code sample

Answer (score 0):

Did you define a column in the model that belongsTo to the primary ActiveRecord as foreign key? Otherwise you won't able to save those records because there is no way of tying those two records together.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship

Comment: Yes, the relationship is declared!